# Boost:asio Verify Certificate synchronous

Tags: c++, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I would like to support synchronous and asynchronous client connections to the server (over TLS). The asynchronous client is trivial, as it is shown in the examples of asio. But how is it possible to connect to the server with TLS in a synchronous manner? My biggest concern is how to check the server certificate. Because asynchronous it is done like this:

```
 asio::ssl::context ctx(asio::ssl::context::tlsv11); 
 ctx.set_default_verify_paths();    
 mSocket(mIoService, ctx);  
 mSocket.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
 mSocket.set_verify_callback(
            std::bind(&Client::verifyCertificate, this,
                      std::placeholders::_1,   
                      std::placeholders::_2));
```

But how can i check the same synchronous?
Note: Currently I'm using the standalone edition of asio. This should be same as for boost:asio.

Edit: the verify methods looks like this

```
bool Client::verifyCertificate(bool preverified,
      asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    //just cout the name
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

    return preverified;
  }
```

Comment: You could just run the io_service with a timeout until you get a callback, if no better approach appears.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how this can solve my problem. Could you please explain in more detail how this would lead to a synchronous communication? (And maybe a snipped of pseudo or samplecode)

Comment: It's pseudo-synchronous, meaning you explicitly run until you have your answer.  This assumes you have an io_service which has no work to do other than this.

Comment: So, uhm. I'm still wondering how to do this technically. I would build a wrapper around the asynchronous functionallity? When should I wait for the timeout? After I called async_connect? When exactly is the verify executed anyway? Because it does not seem that the verify is calling any other method...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to call [`handshake()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/handshake.html).  It's documented as a blocking call, and I assume it will synchronously invoke your certification verification function.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at this method.